# How to change angular material datepicker format

Tags: angular, typescript, date, angular-material2

This is the format of date I am getting when I am using angular material datepicker....`Wed Nov 21 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

But I need date in `(YYYY-MM-DD)` or `(YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm)` this format.

this is model class I am using to capture data from angular material form

```
export class FlightSchedule {

    constructor(
        public destination: string,
        public origin: string,
        public date: string,
        public limit: string
    ) {}

}
```

Please help me, I am unable to convert date in `YYYY-MM-DD` or `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm` format.

I am new to Angular

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are looking for to convert date that you received from `datepicker` or format date inside `datepicker` input?

Comment: I am looking to convert date that I received from datepicker

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You need to provide an object containing the formats you wish to use. The object should look something like:

```
export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'LL',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    monthYearLabel: 'YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'YYYY',
  },
};
```

You then need to add that in to your providers array, like so:

```
  import { MAT_DATE_FORMATS } from '@angular/material/core';
  import { MomentDateAdapter } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';

  //...

  providers: [
    {provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]},
    {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS},
  ],
```

**[Here is a StackBlitz demo to show it working](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d2qoxi-iy68bi?file=app/datepicker-formats-example.ts)**

Comment: Thank you user184994, but I am unable to customize it in my project.  This is my html datepicker format, which i am attaching it now

Comment: <mat-form-field style="margin-top: 20px" class="demo-full-width" class="form-group">
              <input required matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" name="date" placeholder="Date" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="flightSchedule.date">
              <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
              <mat-datepicker touchUi="true" #picker></mat-datepicker>
            </mat-form-field>

Comment: Why are you unable to customize it?

Comment: i believe I am having  class="form-control" but in example it is [formControl]="date", so i unable to use   date = new FormControl(moment()); in app component

Comment: That shouldn't matter... Are you able to create a StackBlitz that demonstrates your code?

Comment: @mmodalities I've just used that HTML in the original Stackblitz and it works fine

Comment: sorry sir, I do not know how to create StackBlitz of my code, please help me so I can share with you

Comment: @mmodalities That stackblitz link appears to be broken

Comment: That stackblitz seems to be erroring when I try to run it

Comment: since I imported it from github so node_modules is added in .gitignore

Comment: so it is showing this error, how to add this package to this project on stackblitz

Comment: this is the project on github https://github.com/mmodal123/lufthansaApp

Comment: Okay, you also need the `MomentDateAdapter` like in my original StackBlitz. I've  just tried that out with your code, and it works

Comment: I want to call api  ----- https://lihcode-lufthansa-open-new-v1.p.mashape.com/v1/operations/schedules/fra/fra/1542652200000?limit=10, but date here is in 1542652200000 format I am getting which results in bad request format

Comment: you can't manually change the date in this solution. it's behave wired

Comment: don't forget to install '@angular/material-moment-adapter' and 'moment'

Comment: How can i show time also with this one like 2021-04-26T00:00:00 ?

Comment: Try changing the year manually to e.g. 4000. It will show the year is invalid! Wired!

Answer (score 28):

No need to use `MomentDateAdapter`!

Here's my solution with the least amount of code *and* using the `MAT_NATIVE_DATE_FORMATS`.

1. Declare your own date formats

```js
import { MatDateFormats, MAT_NATIVE_DATE_FORMATS } from '@angular/material';

export const GRI_DATE_FORMATS: MatDateFormats = {
  ...MAT_NATIVE_DATE_FORMATS,
  display: {
    ...MAT_NATIVE_DATE_FORMATS.display,
    dateInput: {
      year: 'numeric',
      month: 'short',
      day: 'numeric',
    } as Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions,
  }
};
```

2. Use them

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-vacation-wizard',
  templateUrl: './vacation-wizard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./vacation-wizard.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: GRI_DATE_FORMATS },
  ]
})
```

Don't forget to set the appropriate language!

```js
constructor(private readonly adapter: DateAdapter<Date>) {}
this.adapter.setLocale(this.translate.currentLang);
```

That's all!

Comment: what is `this.adapter` ?

Comment: @gyozokudor https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#setting-the-locale-code

Comment: `this.adapter.setLocale("en-EN")` goes into constructor body and adapter becomes a property of that class, that's whay `this.adapter`

Comment: is it possible to set the format programmatically rather than hardcoding it?

Comment: Just as a note to get the YYYY-MM-DD you have to use the Intl formats

`dateInput: { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit' }`

Answer (score 14):

```
import { DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from '@angular/material';
import { MomentDateModule, MomentDateAdapter } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';

 export const DateFormats = {
            parse: {
                dateInput: ['YYYY-MM-DD']
            },
            display: {
                dateInput: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
                dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
                monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
            },
        };

    providers: [

        { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE] },
          { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: DateFormats }

      ],
```

add above code in your app.module. it is working perfectly for me.

Comment: @MSM any way to this this on run time

Comment: How can i show time also with this one like 2021-04-26T00:00:00 ?

Comment: This only works for ng serve and not on production / run time.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  modelChanged(date) {
    var theDate = new Date(Date.parse(date));
    const localDate = theDate.toLocaleString().split(" ");

    console.log(localDate);
  }
```

```html
    <!--I had the same issue and found it that with javascript was simple approach
--->
    
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
          <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
          <input
            matInput
            [matDatepicker]="picker"
            [(ngModel)]="date"
            (ngModelChange)="modelChanged($event)"
          />
          <mat-datepicker-toggle
            matSuffix
            [for]="picker"
          ></mat-datepicker-toggle>
          <mat-datepicker touchUi #picker color="primary"></mat-datepicker>
        </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Upvoted because it works and even it has no explanation, the code is very understandable.

Answer (score 0):

A shortcut way would be to create javascript date object and then format it to whatever format you want. Assuming you have [(ngModel)]="myDate" on your date input, you can do:

```
var formatedDate = new Date(this.myDate).toLocaleString();
```

This is short way of doing what u want :)