# Error on converting mat Calender to form dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: angular, calendar

I have a mat calendar used for filtering service data but the problem is when I tried to convert the picker date format  I found an error on the result for example when the mat calendar data = Fri Apr 17 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0100(West Africa Standard Time) the conversion result 5/3/2020 23:0:017 when the correct data should be = 17/4/2020 00:00:00

my code

```
update_by_date(evt){
    this.Display_clander = false;
    console.log(evt);
    let myDate = new Date(evt);
    console.log(myDate);
  }
```

Comment: Does this helps you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53359773/2976876

Answer (score 0):

I have created a demo for your problem.
[Demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-calendar-z6xzgo?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

where you can check console after selecting a date and you will get the proper result as you expected.
Don't know why did you get a different result.

Comment: ok check https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-calendar-z6xzgo here, for example, I tried to select the day and when I selected it I got an incorrect result

Comment: I got this as a result 2020-04-16T23:00:00.000Z.Is it not correct ?

Comment: I when it like 16/04/2020