# wrong format date mat data picker

Tags: angular, angular-material, datepicker, mat-datepicker

I want show date with this format DD/MM/YYYY. I need to use italian languages with data picker and this format  DD/MM/YYYY.
In my app.module I do this:

```
export const DD_MM_YYYY_Format = {
  parse: {
      dateInput: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
  },
  display: {
      dateInput: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
      monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
      dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
      monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
};
```

and after I do in my providers :

```
 { provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'it-IT' },
   {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: DD_MM_YYYY_Format},
```

So I do in my component and the format is not properly correctly. the result is this:

[image]

the problem is that I want the format '`02/03/2022`' and not '`2/3/2022`'

Comment: Di you checked these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53359598/how-to-change-angular-material-datepicker-format and you followed all the necessary instructions ?

Comment: add a date pipe to your input field ref https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Answer (score 1):

Add a date pipe to your input field ref [angular.io/api/common/DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe).

You seem to be looking for this pipe:

```js
{{ dateObj | date:'dd/MM/YYYY' }}
```