# Get specific format with material datePicker

Tags: angular, date, angular-material, datepicker

I’m working on an app that uses an angular material datepicker.

This datepicker returns a date object in ISO 8601 format
I want to get the format yyyy-MM-dd in string.
For this, I created the following code:

HTML:

```
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>{{ 'commons.consultations.dateTo' | translate }}</mat-label>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="pickerTo" formControlName="dateTo" />
    <mat-datepicker-toggle
      matSuffix
      [for]="pickerTo"
    ></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker
      (closed)="convertDateTo_YYYY_MM_DD_Format()"
      #pickerTo
    ></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
```

ts file:

```
  public convertDateTo_YYYY_MM_DD_Format() {
    this.form
      .get('dateTo')
      ?.setValue(
        this.datePipe.transform(this.form.get('dateTo')?.value, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
      );
  }
```

module.ts (format fr-FR)

```
providers: [{ provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'fr-FR' }, DatePipe]
```

In my code, I have a custom validator that checks that the date is in the format yyyy-MM-dd:

```
export function dateValidator(
  dateTo: string,
): ValidatorFn {
  return (form: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    let dateTo = form.get(dateTo );
    const regEx = /^[12]\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/;

    //...............

    if (dateTo.value?.match(regEx)) {
          // do some stuff.....................
}
```

The problem with this code is that the validator is triggered even before the function call that depends on the event datepicker (closed).

```
(closed)=convertDateTo_YYYY_MM_DD_Format()
```

My question is: is there a way for the datepicker itself to convert the date to the desired format (yyyy-MM-dd) without going through the closed event  before the validator is triggered?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to get the desired date format directly from the datepicker without relying on the closed event. You can use the MatDatepickerInputEvent that is emitted when the user selects a date, and then convert the selected date to the desired format using the DatePipe. Here's an example:

**HTML**

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>{{ 'commons.consultations.dateTo' | translate }}</mat-label>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="pickerTo" formControlName="dateTo" (dateChange)="onDateChange($event)" />
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="pickerTo"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #pickerTo></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

**TS file**

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {}

public onDateChange(event: MatDatepickerInputEvent<Date>) {
  const formattedDate = this.datePipe.transform(event.value, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
  this.form.get('dateTo')?.setValue(formattedDate);
}
```

Updated Code using subscribe method

HTML

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>{{ 'commons.consultations.dateTo' | translate }}</mat-label>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="pickerTo" formControlName="dateTo" />
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="pickerTo"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #pickerTo></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

**TS**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;
  dateToSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private datePipe: DatePipe
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      dateTo: ['', Validators.required],
    });

    // Subscribe to the valueChanges of dateTo form control
    this.dateToSubscription = this.form
      .get('dateTo')
      .valueChanges.subscribe((dateTo: Date) => {
        // If the date is valid, format it and update the form control value
        if (dateTo instanceof Date && !isNaN(dateTo.getTime())) {
          const formattedDate = this.datePipe.transform(dateTo, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
          this.form.get('dateTo').setValue(formattedDate);
        }
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.dateToSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn’t solve the problem...The validator is triggered before the event (dateChange)

Comment: @Olivier Please check my answer i have updated. you can use Subscribe

Comment: not sure that using at the same time dateChange and valuesChanges  is a good idea.
I think the solution is here but I don’t understand how to make it work
https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#customizing-the-parse-and-display-formats

Comment: Or here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53359598/how-to-change-angular-material-datepicker-format